# Replacing commas with x in a list of dictionary (Python)

Tags: python

My Code:

```
for i in range(len(new_list)):
    # Use of Lambda to multiply each number in each list
    nums_product = reduce((lambda x,y: x * y), new_list[i])
    list_product_num.append(nums_product)
print(list_product_num)
x = [{'qns': f , 'ans': c} for f, c in zip(input_list, list_product_num)]
print(x, end= '' )enter code here
```

This is the ouput:

```
[{'qns': [1, 3, 3], 'ans': 9}, {'qns': [2, 5, -1], 'ans': -10}, {'qns': [3, 2], 'ans': 6}, {'qns': [4, 5, 3], 'ans': 60}, {'qns': [0, 23], 'ans': 0}, {'qns': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ans': 24}]
```

However this is the expected output that I have to achieve which is basically, replacing [1,3,3] with '1 x 3 x 3 ':

```
[{'qns': '1 x 3 x 3', 'ans': 9}, {'qns': '2 x 5 x -1', 'ans': -10}, {'qns': '3 x 2', 'ans': 6}, {'qns': '4 x 5 x 3', 'ans': 60}, {'qns': '0 x 23', 'ans': 0}, {'qns': '1 x 2 x 3 x 4', 'ans': 24}]
```

I've been looking for ways around this and would grateful if someone would point me in the right direction,Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your final output in this way:

```
x = [{'qns': ' x '.join(map(str, d['qns'])), 'ans': d['ans']} for d in x]
```

If you want to build the correct output from scratch, just replace your last but one line of code with:

```
x = [{'qns': ' x '.join(map(str, f)) , 'ans': c}
     for f, c in zip(input_list, list_product_num)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `f` with the following:

```
' x '.join([str(num) for num in f])
```

And the result would be like:

```
x = [{'qns': ' x '.join([str(num) for num in f]) , 'ans': c} for f, c in zip(input_list, list_product_num)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for string's built-in method called `join`.
`" x ".join(f)` will not work though because the items in the list `f` are not *strings*. To solve that we can cast every item in a list to strings with a list comprehension: `[str(n) for n in f]`.

Putting it together for your example we can replace `'qns': f` with `'qns': ' x '.join([str(n) for n in f])`

---

You didn't provide values for your input lists, but I'm guessing your only input is a list of lists containing numbers. I took the liberty to create a compact example for you

```
from functools import reduce

new_list = [[1, 3, 3], [2, 5, -1], [3, 2], [4, 5, 3], [0, 23], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

print([{"qns": " x ".join(str(x) for x in l), "ans": reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), l)} for l in new_list])
```

```
>>> [{'qns': '1 x 3 x 3', 'ans': 9}, {'qns': '2 x 5 x -1', 'ans': -10}, {'qns': '3 x 2', 'ans': 6}, {'qns': '4 x 5 x 3', 'ans': 60}, {'qns': '0 x 23', 'ans': 0}, {'qns': '1 x 2 x 3 x 4', 'ans': 24}]
```